# Does the linux command grep search for a string also inside files or just in their names?

Tags: linux, grep

Does the linux command grep search for a string also inside files or just in their names ?

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248761/find-files-containing-string-in-file-name-and-different-string-within-file

Comment: Read the documentation of `grep`. Type `man grep` on your terminal or [read it on the web](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html). `grep` does not care about the file names; `find` is the one that does.

Comment: I see, find is the command to use then. But does it search for a given string INSIDE *.txt files, for instance, and not just in the file names ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `grep` command search inside text file and binary files.

See documentation [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

And examples [here](https://www.tecmint.com/12-practical-examples-of-linux-grep-command/).